# jQuery BubblePopUp is not working without alert, which is working on another page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I used Jquery Bubblepopup plugin for display tool-tips.
BubblePopup is created on mousehover on a div, this div is created dynamically by Jquery's append method. All Jquery functionalities are working fine but this is not working without alert.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //alert($('#mapcontainer a.fixed').length);
  window.setTimeout(function () {

    $('#mapcontainer div.fixed').CreateBubblePopup({
      position: 'top',
      align: 'center',
      divStyle: {
        color: '#000000',
        margin: '-20px 0px 0px 0px'
      },
      innerHtml: 'Add or change location',
      innerHtmlStyle: {
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        'text-align': 'center'
      },
      themeName: 'all-grey',
      themePath: 'images/jquerybubblepopup-theme'
    });
  }, 50);
});
```

- div, anchor, fixed class created by jquery append method

Comment: But when do you create them ? And what do you mean by "works with alert" ? Does your bubble popup appear when you uncomment the laert or simply the alert show `0` or more than zero ?

Comment: Those(div, anchor) are created, when i clicked on some link. When i used any alert message, then it is working otherwise not which is given in ma code. No, First time, with alert message it's working but next time its working with uncomment alert. 
* ANother thing, above code is working on another web page..

Comment: You have to show more code or create a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) to reproduce your problem because I don't really understand the context.

Comment: Now itz working
The problem is createbubblePopup before anchor creation.

Comment: It's may be because your $('#mapcontainer div.fixed') is not ready at that time. When you using alert at that time they find some delay to get ready. That's why it's working when you using alert

Comment: @Wahid4sap It's almost always a race condition issue if a JavaScript works with an alert and not without. The alert takes just enough time for all the elements to be ready for the script to work. Try increasing the SetTimeout's value to something higher than 50.

Comment: I think the problem is the element async creation. Solution, when you create each'#mapcontainer div.fixed' element wireup the plugin using  "$('#mapcontainer div.fixed').CreateBubblePopup". Another solution is to use http://api.jquery.com/on/ and add into mouseover listener the wireup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a very small quantity of delay, then omit the setTimeOut() method and put your function directly inside the ready() method.

And if you may want some time delay while executing. Either you can increase a bit more time so that the whole page will be loaded while executing your code.

The best and efficient manner is to use document.ready() method at the end of your webpage just above the body tag. Surely this technique will resolve your problem.